# Activate context based on the view selected in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to activate a context based on the view selected to add shortcut to a specific view.
I did the following.

- Created Keybinding
- Added Command Handler
- Created Context

But I am not sure how to activate the contact using plugin configuration.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do here and it is not clear that a context is what you want.

Comment: I want to call different commands based on the view from which I pressed the shortcut. For eg. if I do CTRL+S from view 1, it should save without any confirmation. If I do CTRL+S from view 2, it should open a new Message View.

Answer (score 1):

To have a different command 'handler' active for different views use the 'activeWhen' element in the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers' definition.

Something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="view1.View1Handler"
        commandId="command.id">
     <activeWhen>
       <with
           variable="activePartId">
          <equals
              value="view1.id">
          </equals>
       </with>
     </activeWhen>
  </handler>
```

define a different handler for the command for each view.